# Histogram with divided bars

Tags: python, histogram, wolfram-mathematica

I have file with the fluxes as a function of time. Now I need to make a histogram of the all fluxes and also I need put in each bar information about times when given N point occured. The main idea is to divide each bar into N pieces (N is the number of repetitions of a given flux value) and each piece should have a color depending on time (color bar). Is any option to do this easily in Mathematica (or in python)? I have tried `Stacked Bar Chart` option in Mathematica but with no results. If you know any similar problem already resolved I will be very grateful for a link.
Below is part of my code in Mathematica, but on this moment I'm able to get only simple histogram.

```
mydata=Import["MJD_Flux_HR.dat", {"Data"}];
time = mydata[[All, 1]];
Rate = mydata[[All, 2]];

Histogram[Log[Rate], 50, ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle", ChartStyle -> Orange, GridLines -> {None, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed],  AxesLabel -> {log[Flux], N}]
```

Comment: I think there is not a simple way to do this. You will need to build up the figure from graphics primitives. Suggest asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. I've asked (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172011/histogram-with-divided-bars) but till this moment I didn't get any answer with clear idea. Unfortunately I'm not able to response to any comment from users at mathematica webside, so I decided that I will try do it using python, because in case any troubles interactions with you and other users here are possible at least.

Comment: Graphics primitives? Could you sketch out it a little? Becasue I'm struggling how to create for each count range (here 'b') an array with information about counts number N[b] and to put there information about time: time[b]=[...,...,...,N] . An append(time) function doesen't work for me properly, beacuse for each new b in the loop I need new time array. I don'd know if I can declare something like time[b]=append.(time[i])? I've tried it but I got an error. I can send my script if it helps.

Comment: if neither answer on the other site is acceptable that should tell you you arent explaining what you want very well. What do you mean you cant respond?

Comment: I mean that when I clik 'add a comment' (I don't understand one response, the level is too high for me on this moment), it shows me "You must have 50 reputation to comment". Yes, I'm aware that something might be not clear for others but I can't ask about any inaccuracies on that webside (and from my perspective the description there seems to be quite clear).

Comment: you should be able to comment and edit your own question. If not post your comments as an answer and ask a moderator to convert it to to a comment.

Comment: Ok, I'll check if it's possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it! Maybe the method is not pretty, but nonetheless maybe it will be helpful for some of you in the future.

My script:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

mjd, mjd_b, rate, hr, Nb = [], [], [], [], []

data='MJD_Flux_HR_002_039.txt'
N=0
with open(data,'r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in lines:
       mjd.append(float(row[0]))
       rate.append(float(row[1]))
       hr.append(float(row[2]))
       N+=1 

for b in range(0,200):
   d=0
   for i in range(0,N):
       k=b+1
       if rate[i] > b and rate[i] < k:
           d=d+1
           with open('Hist_data.dat','ab') as f:
               np.savetxt(f, [[b, d,mjd[i]]],delimiter=" ", fmt=('%2.0d','% 3.0d','% 3.5f'))
           Nb.append(d)
           mjd_b.append(mjd[i])

   del Nb[:]
   del mjd_b[:]
```

and as a result I got file which I was able to plot.
b is here a range of fluxes (between 0 and 1, 1 and 2, etc. [counts/s]), d is needed not to count how many times given flux range ocuured but more to place every repetition on Y axis with the associated time (color). 
I enclosed an image is in the ling below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX2pN.jpg)